# Using Arduino Wifi Shield to Receive Signal

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to use an Arduino Uno with Arduino Wifi Shield 101 to receive a signal from phone or webpage over wifi so it will "initiate" my circuit. I was able to connect the board to wifi but am unsure on how I should continue. My main goal is to be able to send it two different commands that would run different parts of code in my arduino script. I am very new to this stuff! Thanks :)

Comment: use the arduino to serve a web page that has a button

Answer (score 1):

Look for the Web Server example in the arduino IDE.  That will give you a starting point to allow you to control the arduino via a web page.  This tutorial is also very in depth : https://startingelectronics.org/articles/arduino/switch-and-web-page-button-LED-control/